# Access Denied Error When using Windows Authentication Mode for WebServices

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, security

I have Windows application which calls one of my WebService. I am using **Windows Authentication Mode** for my WebService. 
a)When I try to access the Web Service it throws an error:

```
System.Net.WebException: The request failed with HTTP status 401: Access Denied.
```

I have set

And also I have switched off **Anonymous Mode** for the WS. only **Integrated Windows Authentication** is checked.

b)When I switch off impersonate then I get the following error:

```
Login failed for user  "My Sys No\ASPNET".
```

I think my Login id credentials is not passed , not sure why is it so as still **Windows Authentication Mode** is On.

can somebody throw light on this?

Comment: Are you referring to ASMX web services? And what version of .NET are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that when you use windows authentication in IIS, the process still runs as the usual user (e.g. ASPNET account on Win 2k and XP), and the authenticated users security token is added to the thread that is actually running the request.

Try to enable Anonymous mode first and make sure you can get it to work (i.e. ASPNET has access to all folders, etc it needs)

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the Credentials property of your web service proxy instance ?

e.g. something like :

```
yourProxyObject.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

Comment: Just to add to this. Ensure that the application or site calling the web service is also using Windows Authentication. If the calling site or app is not using Windows Authentication the service will only receive authentication tickets as ASPNET user or NT_SERVICE

Answer (score 0):

How are you refering to the webservice? I had a problem where if I referred to it as http://localhost/... instead of http://servername/... it wouldn't pass the credentials to the webservice.

Also it sounds like you're hitting the webservice once you turn on anonymous access. If you grant the IUSR access to the database it may work. If so then it would seem to be a problem passing credentials.